# How to find a record with two specific fields? SQL many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning SQL, and I'm having trouble writing a query to find games that have multiple genres at the same time.

I have a table like this:

| game | genre |
| --- | --- |
| Void City | horror |
| Void City | survival |
| Paranoid | survival |
| Paranoid | thriller |
| Circle beat | action |
| Circle beat | horror |

So how to write a query that returns list of action + horror games?, I expect to get only **Circle beat** in this case

Comment: Post what you have tried so far so we can help guide your learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
select game
    from game_table
    where genre in ('action')
intersect 
select game
    from game_table
    where genre in ('horror');
```

Comment: Please be aware that (sadly) `intersect` isn't supported by all database vendors e.g. see https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/intersect-all

Comment: INTERSECT is pretty common across most database vendors (some with support for ALL or DISTINCT modifiers).  The modern-sql.com/caniuse/intersect-all is a bit misleading.  BigQuery, MySQL, SQL Server, and others support one or more forms of INTERSECT.

Comment: MySQL does not support Intersect (as at v8.0.27). Some implementations allow `intersect distinct` others don't allow the distinct operator, fewer allow 'all'. It's a mess IMHO and I prefer to avoid it as I have also prefer to keep my code as interoperable as possible.

Comment: I stand corrected, the link that I quickly checked explained how to emulate it after showing the common syntax for MySQL:  https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php

Comment: Useful information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, with a single pass of the table, is to use a having clause like so:

```
select
       game
from game_table
where genre in ('action','horror')
group by
       game
having (  max(case when genre ='action' then 1 else 0 end) 
        + max(case when genre ='horror' then 1 else 0 end) ) = 2
```

note, a `having clause` can filter the results of an aggregation function such as `max()` (maximum) - but a `where` clause cannot do that. But, you can use both clauses in a single query as you can see above, the where clause reduces the total number of rows to be considered and the having clause considers some aggregated data to filter out rows that don't meet the wanted aggregated data conditions.

Comment: Thank you! It works too.
I also tried to change your query for the sake of experiment and wrote **having** part like this:
`having (COUNT(game)> 1)`.
Will it work worse than your version?

Comment: `having (COUNT(game)> 1)`  could be true if there were 2 or more rows with value 'horror' in the genre column - it does NOT prove that there is BOTH 'action' AND `horror` - my version of the having clause does ensure you have BOTH

Comment: btw: well done trying that alternative approach - it is good to see you trying new things!